# Class App\Articles not found

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using Laravel 5.2 and I renamed my Model from "Articles" to "Article". I did the same for the class as well as the controller, but I am having an error in "show" method in my controller.

> ReflectionException in Container.php line 738:

Here is my controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Requests\ArticleRequest;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Article;
use App\User;
use App\Tag;
use Auth;

class ArticlesController extends Controller
{

public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth');
}

public function index()
{
    $articles = article::latest('created_at')->get();

    return view('articles.home', compact('articles'));
}

public function show(Article $article)
{
    return view('articles.show', compact('article'));
}

public function create()
{
    $tag = Tag::lists('name', 'id');

    return view('articles.create', compact('tag'));
}

public function store(ArticleRequest $request)
{
    $article = Auth::user()->article()->create($request->all());

    $article->tags()->attach($request->input('tags'));

    flash('Your Article Has Been Successfully Saved','Good Job');

    return redirect('articles');
}

public function edit(Article $articles)
{
    return view('articles.edit', compact('articles'));
}

public function update(Article $articles, ArticleRequest $request)
{
    $articles->update($request->all());

    return redirect('articles');
}

}
```

Here is my Model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Article extends Model
{
    protected $table = "articles";

    protected $fillable = [
        'title',
        'body',
        'published_at',
        'user_id'
    ];

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }

    public function tags()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Tag')->withTimestamps();
    }
}
```

Here is the route registered:

```
 Route::resource('articles','ArticlesController');
```

Finally Here's my show.blade.php:

```
@extends('app')

@section('content')

<h2>{{ $article->title }}</h2>

<div class="body">
    <p>{{ $article->body }}</p>
</div>

@stop
```

Comment: Did you try to use ´composer dump-autoload´?

Comment: In your tag model, in the articles method, are you referring to it as belongsToMany('App\Article or App\Articles?

Comment: yes i did .. didn't work :( @fmgonzalez

Comment: App\Article .. but the method's name is 'articles' is that a problem ? @Birdman

Comment: If you're using explicit route model binding, did you update `RouteServiceProvider`? If you aren't, your route is `articles` and your model is `article` so Laravel is not able to implicitly bind it anymore.  Change the route to `Route::resource('article')`

Comment: It Worked Thanks So Much :) .. Can I mark your answer as a correct answer to help others ? @Jeff

Comment: Nice!  I added an answer for future readers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're using explicit route model binding, did you update `RouteServiceProvider` with the new class name?

If you aren't using explicit binding, your route is `articles` and your model is `Article` so Laravel is not able to implicitly bind it anymore. Change the route to `Route::resource('article')` and it should work.